# Primeng Input placeholder doesn't show by default and showing up only after a click

Tags: angular, input, primeng

Primeng input field placeholder is visible only after clicking on it. We have this issue only after upgrading from PrimeNg 13 to 15.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Some text" />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a PrimeNG input, you would need the `pInputText` for that. Could you share a realistic code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by adding a opacity

```
.p-float-label {
    input {
        &::placeholder {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```